# Why does assigning a value to $? crash Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Running the code `$? = $true` in powershell crashes the program with a "powershell has stopped working" windows error message.

Some builtins like `$true` or `$host` throw an error: `Cannot overwrite variable true because it is read-only or constant.`. Others like `$myinvocation` or `$null` are just ignored. Why is `$?` different? Is there documentation on which builtins have which response? [`help about_automatic_variables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Automatic_Variables?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) doesn't have any details.

I'm currently running version 5.1. I also tried using `powershell -version $n '$? = $true'` and versions 3-5 all crash. Interestingly, versions 1 and 2 do not; they throw the read-only variable error.

Comment: Do you want a disassembly of the code that demonstrates why it crashes, or do you want to know if it's supposed to do this? The answer to the latter is a definite no. Silly bug is a bug. PowerShell 3 was a substantial new release that transitioned PowerShell to the Dynamic Language Runtime; a bunch of behavior changed along with it. Some beneficial, some surprising, and some just plain buggy. This appears to be one of the latter cases.

Comment: I was wondering if it was intentional/documented. Interesting about version 3 and the DLR, I hadn't heard about that before. Is there somewhere to send the bug report or should I just not worry about it?

Comment: Weird. PSVersion 5.0.10586.117 throws `Cannot overwrite variable ? because it is read-only or constant.`

Comment: Side note: the only value that "works" for the `-version` parameter is `2` or `2.0`. Using any version `<=2` will use the 2.0 engine. Using any version `>=3` will give you the highest version available on the system. Curiously trying to use point releases like `1.1` or `2.1` failed:  `Cannot start Windows PowerShell. No version of Windows PowerShell compatible to x.1 is installed.`

Comment: PS Version 5.0.10586.67 , doesn't crashes, Can you post the full version info ?

Comment: @PRASOONKARUNANV `$PSVersionTable` says `5.1.14393.576`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this is a [known bug](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/16977433-assigning-a-value-to-false-crashes).
The fix was added to the version that is currently in works (6.0). You can find related pull request [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/2320).

My guts tell me that the reason for different behaviour (when compared to other automatic variable) is the fact that both you and system tries to write to this variable virtually at the same time. And even though I don't know why you would want to write to it (I suspect it all started with some `if ($? = $true)` ...), I do agree that one is really nasty.